# How to detect pings inside a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, denial-of-service

We are trying to perform a Denial Of Service attack as an Internet Security project so we have a client and a server set up.
The client performs the following

```
private void pingAttack() throws Exception {
    String url = "127.0.0.1";
    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(url);
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 1000000000; counter++) {
        System.out.println(inet.isReachable(5000) ? "available" : "NA");
    }
}
```

In the server, I need to counter measure this so I need to detect the pings sent and disconnect from user after a specific amount of pings but I don't know how to do this. What should we write in the server side in the `doGet()` method?

Comment: This sounds more like a firewall/OS level provision than inside a servlet.  Most servlets only handle http/https protocols so they don't really see icmp messages.  Is this actually a servlet or just a service listening on a particular port?

Comment: I have very limited experience with servlets programming. I thought that I could do something from the server side but from the answers this appears to be not possible. Can I know what is the difference between servlet and service listening on a port? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`isReachable` does not result in an HTTP request, thus your `doGet`, doXXX methods will never be invoked.

From the InetAddress's [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int))

> Test whether that address is reachable. Best effort is made by the
>   implementation to try to reach the host, but firewalls and server
>   configuration may block requests resulting in a unreachable status
>   while some specific ports may be accessible. A typical implementation
>   will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege can be obtained,
>   otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo)
>   of the destination host.

However, if you're trying to prevent DoS of HTTP requests, it's possible to configure the container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc) to only accept a maximum number of concurrent requests, after which further requests are ignored.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I could do something from inside the server so I can show to my prof. Is there an OS script that i can write for example to do this. we use apache

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. If they trick you to execute the doGet() you're already loading your server. You should look into your firewall configuration.

Comment: I understand that I cannot handle from the doGet() method but I dont want to handle this via a firewall